# winrs using backtick in perl hangs

Tags: perl, winrs

I ran the following winrs command using backtick (``) in perl script,

```
$result = `winrs -r:<system_name> d:\tmp\transfer_remove_file.bat`
```

winrs windows is hangs after executing and it didn't return the output, after I close the window, I am able to see the output of winrs command.

As I need to capture the winrs result, I am using backtick, if I use system() call, it is not hanging, but i am not able to capture the output.

I can redirect the output of winrs to a file and use system(), like as follow,

```
system( winrs -r:<system_name> d:\tmp\transfer_remove_file.bat >> testlog.txt )
```

but when using multiple winrs in the same script and doing the redirect to same file, getting the following error

> the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Please help me to address this issue

Comment: You have to escape the backslashes or use forward slashes.  That means, replace the path either with "d:\\tmp\\transfer_remove_file.bat" or "d:/tmp/transfer_remove_file.bat".  You probably have more bugs in your script but that will maybe bring you one step forward.

Comment: try run it as open(my $ph, "comand |"); https://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html. then select it by IO::Select and read it in a loop when it possible.

Comment: I am getting this error message, after using open with pipe and IO::Select

    "Winrs error:The pipe is being closed."